# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta}{4}\left(y^2+x^2-1\right)^2\right)dy$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, bessel-functions

I'm interested in the following integral:
\begin{equation}
P_\beta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta}{4}\left(y^2+x^2-1\right)^2\right)dy,
\end{equation}
where $\beta>0$.

For context, this integral comes from the probability density function of the displacement (or velocity) of a Van der Pol-Rayleigh oscillator, as shown by [Talmadge 1991](https://doi.org/10.1121/1.400958) (eqn. 9).

This integral is very similar in form to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013095/1098455) question which has already been answered on here, however Did's method was only correct for $a>0$, $b >0$. For my specific case, $b<0$ ($x^2-1<0$) forms an important solution case. Through some trial and error with Mathematica/MATLAB, I was able to find the general solution for my case:

\begin{equation}
P_\beta(x) = \sqrt{|x^2-1|}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta}{4}\left(x^2-1\right)^2\right) F(x^2-1,\beta),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
F(x^2-1,\beta) = \sqrt{2}{K}_{1/4}\left(\frac{\beta}{4}\left(x^2-1\right)^2\right)+2 H\left(-(x^2-1)\right){I}_{1/4}\left(\frac{\beta}{4}\left(x^2-1\right)^2\right),
\end{equation}

and where $I_{\nu}(z)$, $K_{\nu}(z)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively, and where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. When $x^2-1>0$, I can see how the solution is formed, but I'm struggling with the $x^2-1<0$ case. Any insights or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\beta>0$. Note that by [$(12.5.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.5.E1)
\begin{align*}
P_\beta  (x) &= 2\exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{2}(x^2  - 1)^2 } \right)\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{2}y^4  - \beta y^2 (x^2  - 1)} \right){\rm d}y} 
\\ & = \exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{2}(x^2  - 1)^2 } \right)\frac{1}{{\beta ^{1/4} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{ - 1/2} \exp \left( { - \tfrac{1}{2}t^4  - \sqrt \beta  (x^2  - 1)t} \right){\rm d}t} 
\\ & = \exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{4}(x^2  - 1)^2 } \right)\frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{\beta ^{1/4} }}U( 0,\sqrt \beta  (x^2  - 1)),
\end{align*}
where $U$ is one of the [parabolic cylinder functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2). If $x^2>1$, then by [$(12.7.10)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.7.E10) this further simpliefies to
$$
\exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{4}(x^2  - 1)^2 } \right)\sqrt {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}{2}} K_{1/4} \!\left( {\tfrac{\beta}{4} (x^2  - 1)^2 } \right).
$$
If $x^2<1$, we may write it as
$$
\exp \left( { - \tfrac{\beta }{4}(x^2  - 1)^2 } \right)\frac{\pi }{{\beta ^{1/4} }}V(0,\sqrt \beta  (1 - x^2 ))
$$
by [$(12.2.15)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2.E15).

Comment: Having checked the results numerically using a MATLAB implementation of [parabolic cylinder functions](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22620-parabolic-cylinder-functions), we can see the results at the [link](https://imgur.com/zmDeMsB) provided. A value of $\beta=100$ is used and compared with numerically integrated values. Although it should be noted that the slope is correct in the solution given in the bounds $x^2<1$, it appears that the values diverge within these bounds.

Comment: I checked it with Wolfram Mathematica's built in parabolic cylinder function + direct numerical integration. They match for all real $x$. Of course they should, because my derivation is correct.

Comment: One aspect missing from your answer is the obtaining of the form of the integral which I asked in my original question. Doing some additional digging, in Miller 1955 (Tables of Webers Parabolic Cylinder Functions), page 79, eqn 243, we have $V(0,x)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x}\mathcal{g}_{1/4}$, where $I_{-n}+I_{n} = \cos{n\pi}\mathcal{g}_{1/4}$ (eqn. 235), where the argument of $\mathcal{g}_{1/4}$ is taken to be $\frac{1}{4}x^2$ (page 77). Using this in combination with [10.27.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27#E2), we can obtain the form of the integral which I asked in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your note. While answering your question, I tried to access Miller's paper but without a success. Of course, it should follow from connection formulae for parabolic cylinder and Bessel functions.

Comment: I had to go to a library and scan the relevant pages. Unfortunately Miller 1955 isn't available online anywhere. I can provide the relevant scans if necessary